# Perl 5.6 script requires (calls) a Perl 5.10 script

Tags: perl, shebang

I have a script foo.pl whose sheebang line points to Perl 5.6 binary. foo.pl "require"s another script bar.pl that has sheebang line having Perl 5.10.

Has anyone ever come across such situation? Any help would be appreciated.

P.S. Due to dependency in the project, it is not possible to change scripts that use 5.6 to latest Perl version. So, I need to live with whatever is there.

Comment: Makes no sense to `require`s a script. [`do`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/do.html) should be used for files with no `package`.

Comment: Note that pointing to a 5.10 installation of Perl in the shebang doesn't make it a "Perl 5.10 script". It just means the system will use that installation of Perl if asked to execute the script.

Comment: What I am trying to understand is, whether the "called" script will be compiled using Perl 5.6 or 5.10?

Comment: Neither `require` nor `do` load a new interpreter. It wouldn't make sense to load a module in a new interpreter since you wouldn't be able to see what you loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`require`'d script will be required in current interpreter - 5.6, no matter what shebang says. It's only important for "startup" script. If that script uses syntax, features or otherwise depends on being run under Perl above 5.6, it will, obviously, either fail completely or will give incorrect results.

Comment: You mean Bar.pl (require'd script) would fail, have I got it correct?

Comment: Yes, if it really depends on being run under 5.10. Actually it will fail at compile time if it have something like explicit `use 5.10;` in it.

Comment: It doesn't have explicit `use 5.10`. But, some of the Perl 5.10 specific features may not work, is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes. Perl 5.6 isn't Perl 5.10. e.g. Regex with `\K` will fail.

Answer (score 0):

The leading hash (#) in the bar.pl shebang will make that line look like a comment when foo.pl 'require's bar.pl.

You should not have a problem.

Comment: Perl actually does process the `#!` line, so claiming it's ignored as a comment isn't true. Try creating a file containing `#!/bin/echo foo` then running that script using `perl script.pl`. Or try creating a file containing `#!/usr/bin/perl -w` and notice how the warnings are on even when running that script using `perl script.pl`.

Comment: Well, crap. My answer is withdrawn.

Comment: You can actually withdraw it by deleting it.

Comment: and hide the fact that I'm imperfect? :-)